# how to set textbox format ###-###-### using regular expression validator?

Tags: c#, asp.net

how do i set validation expression using this type of format ###-###-### this is for TIN number(Philippines). if not possible format like 9 numbers and 3 - .

Comment: try to put your effort in your question. What you have done so far.

Answer (score 2):

Use this regular expression in `RegularExpressionValidator`:

```
\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{3}
```